# PHP detect cookie value and redirect

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to detect if a cookie named "authenticated" has a value of "true" if so redirect.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    $named_cookie= "authenticated";
    if($_COOKIE[$named_cookie] === "true"){
    flush();
    header( 'Location: https://app.website.com' );
    exit (); }
```

For whatever reason it works in chrome but not in FF or IE

Comment: In Firefox it shows an error or something? Or just do nothing....can you please comment the `header` line and put this one `var_dump($_COOKIE[$named_cookie]);`, test it on Firefox and post the output?

Comment: Done. In chrome it says 'string(4) "true"' but in FF nothing happens.

Comment: try clear your cache and cookies then try again, but i don't think thats the reason

Comment: Ok, I think that I got it....If you are setting the cookie using setcookie, can you post the code where you set the cookie?

Comment: @Hackerman `'string(4) "true"'` not ``bool`` that means its sat and has the value `"true"` not bool `TRUE` if you thinking about that

Comment: @xYuri he also checks for the string "true" later: `if($_COOKIE[$named_cookie] === "true")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I am hosting my site on WPEngine and they dont allow cookie access with PHP it all has to be dont via AJAX and JS.

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
<?php
$named_cookie= "authenticated";
if(isset($_COOKIE[$named_cookie]) && $_COOKIE[$named_cookie] == "true"){
header('Location: https://app.website.com');
exit(); }
?>
```

;)

Comment: i don't this that you need the `flush()`